# Is it possible to avoid storing username and password in settings.xml in Jenkins?

Tags: passwords, configuration, credentials

In the project's source files there is `settings.xml`, which according to the official documentation contains the credentials of the servers jenkins needs to authenticate, but in plain text. Is there best practice or any way to follow in order to avoid storing the credentials in plain text and not brake jenkins' functionality?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/753741/settings.xml?version=1&modificationDate=1349199582000

```
[...]

<servers>
<!--
server | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below). | | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are | used together. | 
<server> 
    <id>deploymentRepo</id> <username>repouser</username> <password>repopwd</password> 
</server> 
-->
<!--
Another sample, using keys to authenticate. 
<server> 
    <id>siteServer</id> 
    <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey> 
    <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase> 
</server> 
-->
</servers>

[...]
```

Comment: This looks like a really Jenkins-specific config question. Isn't this a question for Jenkins?